# Statement to tell me the username already exists

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

The below query is not telling me the username already exists in the database even though it does.

I am trying to learn how to bind parameters etc. but have confused myself somewhere I think.

```
<?php
    // Include config.php
    require_once("".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/admin/config.php");

    // top.inc.php
    require_once($top_inc);
?>

<!-- Meta start -->
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<!-- Meta end -->

<!-- CONTENT START -->

<?php
    // sidebar.inc.php
    require_once($sidebar_inc);

    // main.inc.php
    require_once($main_inc);

    // check if form has been submitted
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['submit'])){

        // initialize form errors array
        $error    = array();

        // fetch form data
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $email    = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        // validate form data
        if(!preg_match(constant("USERNAME_REGEX"), $username)){
            $error[] = "Please enter a username. Use 3 to 15 digits and letters";
        }
        if(!preg_match(constant('PASSWORD_REGEX'), $password)){
            $error[] = "Please enter a password. Minimum of 6 characters required";
        }
        if(!empty($password) && $password == $username){
            $error[] = "Your pasword cannot be you username for security reasons";
        }
        if(empty($email)){
            $error[] = "Please enter your email address";
        }
        if(!empty($email) && !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            $error[] = "Your email address is not valid";
        }

        // connect to database
        sql_con();

        // Get instance of statement
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connect);

        // sql statement
        $UserExists = "
                    SELECT
                        `user_login`
                    FROM
                        `users`
                    WHERE
                        `user_login` = ? ";

        // prepare sql statement for execution
        if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $UserExists)) {

            // bind parameters [s for string]
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username) or die(mysqli_stmt_error());
            // execute statement
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) or die(mysqli_stmt_error());
            // check if username is found
            if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) > 0 ){
                $error[] = 'The username you have choose has already been taken';
            }
        }

        // If errors found display errors
        if(!empty($error)){
            foreach($error as $msg){
                echo "$msg <br />";
            }
    } else {
            echo 'My Query Worked!';
        }
    }
    // signup.tpl template location
    $tpl = 'inc/tpl/signup.tpl';
    // load signup form template
    PageContentTemplate($tpl);
?>

<!-- CONTENT FINISH -->

<?php
    // footer.inc.php
    require_once($footer_inc);
?>
```

Basically it just echos out 'My Query Worked' even though it should say the username is already taken which it is, I enter details on the form and a username I know that has been taken and submit the form, I know I am doing something probably really silly but being new to mysqli and binding parameters etc. I don't know where I am going wrong even though I have looked at some examples.

To be honest, I am not sure if this is the best way to do it in procedural style, I don't know PDO/OOP, my main reason to change is to avoid SQL injection by using placeholders etc. in my queries.

Comment: @Michael, i added `or die(mysqli_stmt_error());` at end of `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username)` and  `mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)` but says my query worked still even thou username does exist in database, basically not got any errors.

Comment: then fetch the rows from your query and see what you actually got.

Comment: @Michael, i just tried and it echoed out the username from db, somewhat confused now :/

Comment: And if you `var_dump($error)` before the `if(!empty())`, does it look like the error has been appended to your array?

Comment: @Michael, it shows `array(0) { }` so error not being caught if i am thinking correctly ? even thou errors for if username, password and email empty or email not valid all work and displays the errors, plus that error i am having the problem with is part of the errors array and there are no typos so i can only guess i am doing something wrong when checking ` if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) > 0 ){ $error[] = 'The username you have choose has already been taken'; }`

Comment: @Michael, i edited my code in original post so you can see the entire file. Thanks phplover

Comment: you'll have to check the value of `mysqli_stmt_num_rows()` not sure why it wouldn't be 1.

Comment: @Michael, i echoed out `mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt)` like `echo mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);` and it shows a value of 0, i am baffeled to be honest why it's not returning 1. Thanks phplover

Comment: I see it now. Answered below - sorry it took me so long :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see it now. You have not called `mysqli_stmt_store_result()` before which `mysqli_stmt_num_rows()` won't report the correct value.

```
    // prepare sql statement for execution
    if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $UserExists)) {

        // bind parameters [s for string]
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username) or die(mysqli_stmt_error());
        // execute statement
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) or die(mysqli_stmt_error());

        // check if username is found
        // FIRST : store the store the result set so num_rows gets the right value
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

        // Now this should be 1 instead of 0
        if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) > 0 ){
            $error[] = 'The username you have choose has already been taken';
        }
    }
```

[From the docs:](http://www.php.net/manual/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php)

> Returns the number of rows in the result set. The use of mysqli_stmt_num_rows() depends on whether or not you used mysqli_stmt_store_result() to buffer the entire result set in the statement handle.
>
> If you use mysqli_stmt_store_result(), mysqli_stmt_num_rows() may be called immediately.

Comment: Thank you Michael, can i ask if there a simpler method using procedural style ? compared to the normal mysql it seems allot of extra coding for the same thing, also is it advised to still use mysqli_real_escape_string even when using placeholders in SQL statement ? i keep thinking to myself what if someone could still somehow inject code and maybe it is still advisable to use `mysqli_real_escape_string`. I do filter input but still would like to know. Thanks very much! phplover :)

Comment: @PHPLOVER You don't need to escape when using placeholders in a prepared statement.  I don't care for procedural style with MySQLi because of all the extra parameters needed for function calls, especially with prepared statements it gets confusing.  Even if the rest of your codebase is not OO, I recommend starting to use OO MySQLi instead of procedural - it just comes out so much cleaner. The res of your code doesn't have to be OO to use MySQLi that way. Prepared statements require more code but are really beneficial so it's right to move to MySQLi or PDO from `mysql_*`.